# Proof of SSS congruence theorem

Tags: geometry

I want proof of SSS congruence rule in Geometry. I have tried to prove it by taking that all angles are equal i.e 60 degree. Then I applied SAS rule of congruence to prove it

Comment: Why are all angles $60$ degree?

Comment: because sum of all angles in a triangle is 180 degree and since all angles in an equilateral triangle are equal, each must be 60 degree

Comment: @ADDechaudhari Not the sides of *one* triangle are supposed to be equal here. Instead, the *corresponding* sides of two triangles are equal.

Comment: You are right. I have solved the problem by doing some construction

Answer (score 1):

> Two triangles are congruent if their corresponding sides are equal in length and their corresponding angles are equal in size.

If you are given that corresponding sides are equal in length, you can easily apply the [Cosine Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) and obtain that each of the corresponding angles are also equal. Hence the two triangles are congruent.

For a more basic proof, refer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564940/proof-for-sss-congruence).

Comment: Did you mean Law of Sines?

Comment: @zahbaz What I meant was the Law of Cosines, but the Law of Sines would probably work as well.

Comment: This is a problem for std IX where trigonometry is not introduced. so please prove it without cosine rule

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** In how many points can two circles intersect?

Let $ABC,DEF$ be two triangles with $|AB|=|DE|\ne0$, $|BC|=|EF|$, $|AC|=|DF|$.
Since a translation can transport $D\to A$, we may assume wlog. that $D=A$. Then a rotation around $A$ can take $E$ to the ray $AB$; since $|DE|=|AB|$, this rotation would take $E\to B$, so that we may assume wlog. that additionally $B=E$.
Now $C,F$ are two points with the same distance to $A$, hence are on a circle around $A$. Similary, they are both on a circle around $B$: They are points of intersection of two distinct circles. If $F=C$, we are done. If $F\ne C$, then reflecting the figure at $AB$ leaves $A,B$ fixed as well as the circles having these points as center, hence permutes the points of intersection. There are only two such points of intersection and the permutation is non-trivial, hence it takes $F\to C$, thus showing the desired congruence.

(While the above argument may be quite *persuading*, the details depend on the axiom system actually used.)

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more and show how this is relevant to the question?